# Liferay, Freemarker error template from search but not from other link

Tags: liferay, freemarker

Using liferay 7 GA4 and freemarker engine.

We encountered a strange behaviour with the freemarker engine.

We have a bunch of web contents using all the same .ftl template.

Here is the begining of the template:

```
<#assign journalArticleId = .vars['reserved-article-id'].data>
<#assign journalArticleResourceLocalServiceUtil = 
staticUtil["com.liferay.journal.service.JournalArticleResourceLocalServiceUtil"]>
<#assign assetCategoryLocalServiceUtil = staticUtil["com.liferay.asset.kernel.service.AssetCategoryLocalServiceUtil"]>
<#assign articleResourcePK = journalArticleResourceLocalServiceUtil.getArticleResourcePrimKey(groupId, journalArticleId)/>
<#assign categories = assetCategoryLocalServiceUtil.getCategories("com.liferay.journal.model.JournalArticle",articleResourcePK) >
<#list categories as category>
<#if category?is_first>
    <#assign categorie = category.getName()>
</#if>
</#list>
<#assign serviceContext = staticUtil["com.liferay.portal.kernel.service.ServiceContextThreadLocal"].getServiceContext()>
<#assign themeDisplay = serviceContext.getThemeDisplay() />

<#assign currentUrl = themeDisplay.getPortalURL() + themeDisplay.getURLCurrent() />
```

And here is the error :

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUDLM.png)

On a public page we have an asset publisher listing all these web contents.

When clicking on one of these everything is fine and the web content is correctly rendered.

Now if we search for this web content via the search portlet, it's also correctly rendered.

The problem is : if we decide to search for the web content before using the asset publisher, the freemarker engine is not able to deal with the template.

In fact we got [this](https://web.liferay.com/fr/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/94828121) kind of error.

The best part is that after you get the error via search, you still can't display it via the asset publisher. Everything is finally broken in that case.

I sincerely think that we tried every solution regarding freemarker engine (portal-ext.properties, freemarker allowed/restricted class etc).

I can't understand why if we come from any other page that can display these web contents it's working fine, but not at all if we search for it at strat.

Thanks for you help everybody.

Edited with template and error

Edit #2 : Here is the error when switching to serviceLocator :

[serviceLocatorError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Zbme.png)

Comment: Please add your code and files so we can help you

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `staticUtil` to retrieve the `DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil`, try to use the `serviceLocator` instead:

```
<#assign DLFileEntryLocalService = serviceLocator.findService("com.liferay.document.library.kernel.service.DLFileEntryLocalService")>
```

**NB.**

You had to enable the serviceLocator in your templates:

Go to `Control Panel -> Configuration -> System Settings -> Foundation -> FreeMarker Engine -> Restricted Variables` and remove serviceLocator then restart Liferay.

Comment: Yes we already tried to switch to serviceLocator and the restricted variables had been removed. But still the same. The problem is that it's working correctly if we don't use the search portlet

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the restriction from serviceLocator by putting this in the portal-ext.properties

```
template.engine.service.locator.restrict=false
```